# Firebase Database Query Not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a Firebase Login and Register App. I have setup that At the time of registration android id will save to the database. If the Android Id exits with another account the user can't create account . when i run the app and try to register an account its shows "Registering Please Wait..." and nothings happens . How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you check inside DatabaseError?

Comment: No. Is my code is ok?

Comment: what you are getting in UserIdQuery ?

Comment: android Device Id.

Comment: where is your logic for  the Android Id exits with another account the user can't create account ?

Comment: try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969640/1697047

Comment: i don't understand !

Comment: what should i add   if (snapshot.child("Michael").exists())   in the field of "Michael"?

Comment: your "android_id"

Comment: its shows error

Comment: can you able to check what is happening by debug

Comment: i don't said that the child exits i want that child value exists .

Comment: have a look at this answer.!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46702189/login-and-reading-writing-data-in-android-studio-no-error-but-not-working/46712771?noredirect=1#comment80387704_46712771

Comment: That question is not related to my question.

Comment: Any One? Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem and all your problems regarding authentication is suggest you using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

It's very easy to implement and you'll don't have in the future any code to maintain.

To find serial number of Android device please use this code:

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String androidSerialNumber = tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Having this `androidSerialNumber` you can use it to save it in your database.

0down voteaccepted

Another approach will be to change The Rule Of Database like this:

```
{ "rules": 
     { ".read": "true",
       ".write": "auth != null"
     }
 }
```

Comment:  I don't understand.  Can u please write 

Comment: Just follow the stept from the offical documentation (as linked above) and your problem will be solved.

Comment: There is no method which I want.  I already used email and pass Method.  See my code brother.

Comment: There is. Firebase Authentication does this for you.

Comment: or writee it as I want. please see my code which I have usedd.

Comment: Follow these steps from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth)

Comment: I am Asking For Android Id (unique id) Like imei.  not uid brother 

Comment: Check My Code.  I already Done this.  Didn't u check My code!

Comment: The best solution for you is to have in stead of that id as the unique identifier for your user, the `android_id`. After that, just use the exists() method to check if the android_id already exists. So you need to change your database structure a little bit.

Comment: Got it...  Can u please Edit my code? its will help me tp understand.  and Check If I have done any wrong 

Comment: Brother?  Are u there??

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to this .

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Id").setValue(android_id);
progressDialog.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
finish();
}
```

and also dismiss the progressDialog when the query is canceled

```
@Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It will finish the Activity and open ProfileActivity