# SignOut the User When Id is Disabled

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a Login and Register App By `Firebase` . I want to signout the login user when I disable the user's Account . (Disable the user by Console not with Admin SDK).

Comment: What means you "disable"? When you delete an account from Firebase console?

Comment: No buddy . There is a Option named Disable Account . Did u see ?

Comment: @AlexMamo  Brother can u please check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725111/firebase-database-query-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing workaround regarding this problem would be to implement a `disable` flag for users that would allow you to `disable/enable` an account. The default value for this flag woul be `false`. Note that this flag would be stored and maintained in your Firebase database. After this, just attach a listener on that particular flag to see the status of the user. If the status is: `disbale: true` (because I have just disabled the user from the console) then just use:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

for that particular user.

You can also use this in conjunction with security rules so that once an account is disabled, only metadata from admins can be written to the user account.

Comment: Thanks :D . Can u please check this question? please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725111/firebase-database-query-not-working